# Next.js getStaticProps params in context equal '[object Object]' / getStaticProps gets called multiple times

Tags: reactjs, next.js, nextjs-dynamic-routing, getstaticprops

I am trying to understand why getStaticProps is getting called multiple times.

The relevant file is called [postId].js in my pages/posts folder; code below:

```
const MyPost({post}) => {
// Main component in here
}

export default MyPost

export async function getStaticProps(context) {
    const { params } = context;
    console.log('params', params)
    // Call API with params.postId and get postContent
    return {
        props: {
            post: postContent,
        },
        revalidate: 10, // In seconds
    }
}

export async function getStaticPaths() {
    const res = await axios.get(API_URL + '/get-post-ids')
    // Get the paths we want to pre-render based on posts
    const paths = res.data.post_ids.map((id) => ({
        params: { postId: id },
    }))
    return { paths, fallback: 'blocking' }
}
```

This logs

```
params { postId: 'post-1' }
params { postId: '[object Object]' }
```

Why does getStaticProps get called twice? And why is the path parameter in the second render `[object Object]`? Anything i can do to prevent that from happening?

I am trying to call an API with the path parameter and i can see the two requests on my backend, the first one works without an issue, but then the second one causes an error.

Thanks a lot!

EDIT:

Logging out paths in getStaticPaths I get

```
 paths [ { params: { postId: 'post-1' } }, { params: { postId: 'post-2' } } ]
```

so not sure where `[object Object]` comes from...

Answer (score 1):

The `getStaticProps` function is getting called twice because `getStaticPaths` returns a `fallback: 'blocking'` option, which means that when a new page is visited that is not pre-rendered, Next.js will fallback to server-side rendering, and in this case it means that `getStaticProps` will be called again to render the new page.

Regarding the postId being `[object Object]`, it is likely that the object that is being passed as the `postId` parameter is not a string, but an object. It is possible that you are passing an object in the `paths` array that `getStaticPaths` returns. Ensure that the `postId` property of the object passed in the `paths` array is a string, or convert it to a string before passing it to `getStaticPaths`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Got it, and given that as per the Next documentation getStaticProp runs on every refresh in dev mode that would make sense i guess: 1st call "route has not been rendered yet; render now" 2nd call "Page has now been rendered go and fetch"

What i don't get yet is the [object Object] issue, logging out my paths i get

paths  [
  { params: { postId: 'post-1' } },
  { params: { postId: 'post-2' } }
]

Comment: What i don't get yet is the [object Object] issue, logging out my paths i get paths [ { params: { postId: 'post-1' } }, { params: { postId: 'post-2' } } ]...